# Pattern match not matching

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match a pattern for digits. First two digits would be `2` and `5`. There may be more digits e.g. `25`, `253`, `2599`, `255`

For this I have written like

```
Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile("[2][5]*");
if(myPattern.matcher("25").matches()) {
}

if(myPattern.matcher("253").matches()) {
}
```

but it always returns `false`. I am not sure what is wrong with my pattern.

Answer (score 3):

While you can solve this by using the regex suggested by @avinashraj, I want to suggest a better solution using [`String#startsWith`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)), you don't really need regex here:

```
if(myString.startsWith("25")) {
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try the below regex,

```
"25\\d*"
```

What's wrong with your regex `[2][5]*` is, first it matches `2` then it matches only the number 5 zero or more times. But `\d*` matches any digit(0-9) zero or more times.

```
System.out.println("25".matches("25\\d*"));
System.out.println("253".matches("25\\d*"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
String.matches("25\\d*")
```

[image]

OR you cau use

```
String.startsWith("25")
```